# Scrapy: Following Links with regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, scrapy, forum

i want to crawl threads from a german Forum. http://www.musiker-board.de/

The actual different subforums are located at http://www.musiker-board.de/forum

A subforum: musiker-board.de/forum/subforumname

The actual Threads have these adresses: musiker-board.de/threads/threadname

I want to follow all links of all subforums and extract all threads in them,
but the URL of the threads wouldnt match with the start URL anymore.

However if I select "musiker-board.de/" as a start URL it doesnt follow the links of all subforums.

Here is the code:

```
allowed_domains = ["musiker-board.de"]
start_urls = ['http://www.musiker-board.de/forum/'
             ]
rules = (
         Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'forum/\w+']), follow=True),
         Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'threads/\w+']), callback='parse_item'),
         )

def parse_item(self, response):
    #extract items...
```

What should i do to follow all musiker-board.de/forum/subforum and to extract all musiker-forum.de/threads/threadname ?

Comment: I reinstalled scrapy and now it works somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code (made from your snippet) seems to work fine:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class Scrapy1Spider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "musiker"
    allowed_domains = ["musiker-board.de"]
    start_urls = ['http://www.musiker-board.de/forum/'
             ]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'forum/\w+']), follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[r'threads/\w+']), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.logger.info('response.url=%s' % response.url)
```

At least there is this output (truncated):

```
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/peavey-ms-412-userthread.271458/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/peavey-5150-6505-etc-userthread.180295/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/marshall-ma-serie-user-thread.386428/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/h-k-metal-master-shredder-user-thread.250846/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/hughes-und-kettner-grandmeister-user-thread.553487/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/ibanez-userthread.190547/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/hughes-kettner-edition-blue-user-thread.209499/page-2
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/fender-prosonic-userthread.239519/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/fender-prosonic-userthread.239519/page-5
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-steve-morse-signature-e656-user-thread.427802/page-2
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-sovereign-user-thread.136266/page-20
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-steve-morse-signature-e656-user-thread.427802/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-sovereign-user-thread.136266/page-19
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-sovereign-user-thread.136266/page-18
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-invader-user-thread.248090/page-5
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-sovereign-user-thread.136266/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-invader-user-thread.248090/page-4
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/engl-invader-user-thread.248090/page-3
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/fender-cybertwin-userthread.305789/
INFO: response.url=http://www.musiker-board.de/threads/fenders-famose-farbwelten.454766/
```

Comment: Weird, I only get the links crawled that have /forum in them. What version of Scrapy are you using?

Comment: I used for this `Scrapy 1.0.1`.